# How to use a trained network as a branch in another network keras?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

Assume i have network simliar to this:
[image: ICnet]

[ICNet_Keras] (https://github.com/aitorzip/Keras-ICNet/blob/master/model.py)

### train procedure in this repo is wrong!

it has three branches.
resolution 1/4 branch is a pretrained network, with saved weights.
resolution 1/2 branch is part of 1/4 network, and weight-shared with 1/4 (i don't know how)
resolution 1 branch is my customization.

## train procedure is something like this:

1/4 is trained on Cityscapes (for relaxation) saved and reloaded

the first few layers of 1/4 branch are used for feeding resolution 1/2 images

The last branch is for full resolution image.
these branches are related with CFF (Cascade Feature Fusion module).

how can I load 1/4 pretrained weight and train whole network?
how about weight sharing between some layers in 1/4 and 1/2 branch?

## for simplicity you can assume

1/4 has 5 layers trained separately and loaded for finetuning
1/2 has 2 first layers of 1/4 
1 has 2 independent layer
and CFFs are just upsample+concat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have your input tensor:

```
inputs = Input(size)
```

If you trained the model yourself, make sure you train it with a variable image size (it's convolutional, right?): input shape = `(None, None, channels)`.

If not, you will need to rebuild the model with variable image size. Make sure you don't use `Flatten`, it will not support variable image sizes. It will not support weight transfer if you want to use what is after the flatten.

### 1/4

Load your saved model (no need to compile, you are not training it directly):

```
lowRes = load_model(filename, compile=False, custom_objects=if_needed)
```

Pass the inputs through it (maybe do some rescaling first)

```
lowOut = lowRes(inputs)
```

### 1/2

Get the segment from `lowRes`:

```
midRes = Model(lowRes.input, lowRes.layers[1].output)
```

Pass the inputs through it (maybe do some rescaling first)

```
midOut = midRes(inputs)
```

### 1/1

Build whatever it is:

```
....
....
hiRes = Model(....)
```

Pass the inputs through it:

```
hiOut = hiRes(inputs)
```

---

### Old answer

Layers and models can be used more than once, as many times as you need.

**Shared layer:**

Create the layer:

```
layer = Conv2D(....)
```

Use the layer:

```
out1 = layer(input1)
out2 = layer(input2)
out3 = layer(input3)
```

It's the same layer, so, the same weights.

**Shared model:**

A `Model` **is** a `Layer`, so it works exactly the same:

```
model = load_some_model()

branch1_out = model(input_branch1)    
branch2_out = model(input_branch2)
```

**Final model:**

At the end, just create a model defining the input tensors and output tensors:

```
final_model = Model(inputs = input_or_list_of_inputs, 
                    outputs= output_or_list_of_outputs)
```

Comment: thanks, I understood weight sharing. but for the model sharing assume 1/4 is saved, then loaded to model. 1/2 is part of 1/4 (e.g. first 5 layers) in a parallel lane. so I need to redefine it, extract corresponding weight from 1/4 and assign to it (is there a better solution?!). and then add my custom branch. this is where it gets complex!

Comment: Why don't you edit your question with the details of the net you want? The solution is not very difficult.

Comment: and you say Model is Layer. how about the configs in model.compile(), am I gonna clear them for new Model or not?

Comment: I'm trying figure out how to implement my config which is similar to icnet in most terms.but the icnet implementation in keras is wrong.

Comment: Compile only adds the loss function and the optimizer. It's totally unnecessary for the models you are not going to call `fit`. Only the model that you call `fit` needs optimizer and loss.

Comment: Added infos to the answer.